# How to display different posts on each page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have above 500 custom posts in wordpress and I select number of post to be shown as 6 from backend.

On frontend 6 post shows on page and pagingnav shows on top when I go to second page from pagingnav it shows next six posts.
But now I want to filter posts for this I use following code in post template:

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'meta_key' => 'special_offer',
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'special_offer',
            'value' => 1,
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
query_posts( $args );
```

Above code filtered posts correctly and 6 post are shown on page but when I go to second page six posts from first page are repeated.
How to dispaly next six posts on second page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion regarding your comment.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'property',
'paged'=>$paged,
'posts_per_page'=>6,
'meta_key' => 'special_offer',
'meta_query'        => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'special_offer',
        'value' => 1,
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )    ));
```

query_posts( $args );

Actually, you need to write the code **get_query_var('paged')** in above and it's reference will shown on query_posts function.

See above how to use:
 `$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`

Thanks,